# Insert que pide introducir valor del parámetro

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Estoy tratando de insertar registros desde un formulario en dos tablas. El formulario inserta correctamente los datos en la Tabla 1, pero quiero que al hacer clic en una casilla de verificación, también se inserten en la Tabla 2.
Este es mi código:

```
Private Sub Copia_Click()
Dim miSQL As String

miSQL = "INSERT INTO Tabla2 (Nombre, Apellido1, Apellido2) Values(" & Me.Nombre.Value & "," & Me.Apellido1.Value & "," & Me.Apellido2.Value & ");"

DoCmd.RunSQL miSQL

MsgBox "Inserción realizada correctamente"

End Sub
```

Pero cada vez que hago clic en la casilla, un ventana emergente me pide que inserte el valor del parámetro.

El formulario tiene tres cuadros de texto llamados Nombre, Apellido1 y Apellido2. Los campos de la tabla 2 también se llaman igual.

Sabéis dónde está el problema? Mil gracias

Answer (score 2):

Lo he solucionado. Al poner comillas simples en los valores, el registro se ha insertado correctamente.

`miSQL = "INSERT INTO Copiado (Nombre, Apellido1, Apellido2) Values('" & Me.ElNombre.Value & "','" & Me.ElApellido1.Value & "','" & Me.ElApellido2.Value & "');"`